# issue with std::fstream file handle reuse

Tags: c++, fstream

I am not sure what is wrong with this piece of code:

```
fstream file_h("h_input.txt");
        if(file_h.is_open()){
                while(!file_h.eof()){
                        line.clear();
                        getline(file_h, line);
                        v_hrml.push_back(line);
                }
                file_h.close();
                file_h.clear();
       }
       file_h("q_input.txt");
       if(file_h.is_open()){
                while(!file_h.eof()){
                        line.clear();
                        getline(file_h, line);
                        v_queries.push_back(line);
                }
                file_h.close();
                file_h.clear();
       }
```

For the code segment opening `q_input.txt` reusing `file_h`, the compiler generates the following error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}) (const char [12])’
     file_h("q_input.txt");
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a variable.

Change

```
file_h("q_input.txt");
```

to

```
file_h.open("q_input.txt");
```